# Puppet regular expression (grab path in var between quotation marks)

Tags: regex, ruby, yaml, puppet

I have the following yaml:

```
role::project::conf::files:
  entry_01:
    - 'file "/var/project/some_file.txt" 5333;'
    - 'echo no;'
  entry_02:
    - 'file "/var/project/some_other_file.txt" 5334;'
    - 'echo yes;'
  entry_03:
    - 'file "/var/project/extra_file.txt" 5335;'
    - 'echo yes;'
```

then I've used the following regular expression https://regex101.com/r/pVzseA/1 in order to grab the value between those quotation marks (the regex works in regex101.com) but doesn't work in Puppet:

```
each($files) | $files_itm | {
  if $files_itm[1] =~ /"([^"]*)"/ {
    #how to get only the path here in var
  }
}
```

Update, the class:

```
class role::project::conf (
  $files = [],
){
  each($files) | $files_itm | {
    if $files_itm[1] =~ /"([^"]*)"/ {
      notify { "file ${1} seen": }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$files_itm[1] =~ /(?<=")[^"]*(?=")/`?

Comment: Puppet uses the [Ruby flavor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) of regular expressions, so [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) would be a better test site for your purposes.  But Ruby regexes are not particularly unusual, and yours does match the inner double-quoted regions of your strings.

Comment: I've used your example:
    $files_itm[1] =~ /(?<=")[^"]*(?=")/
but I am getting the following error:

Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: Left match operand must result in a String value. Got an Array. at ../files.pp:33:7 on node mytest.server
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've used the following regular expression
> https://regex101.com/r/pVzseA/1 in order to grab the value between
> those quotation marks (the regex works in regex101.com) but doesn't
> work in Puppet:
>
> ```
> each($files) | $files_itm | {
>   if $files_itm[1] =~ /"([^"]*)"/ {
>     #how to get only the path here in var
>   }
> }
> ```

As I noted in comments, Puppet uses Ruby's flavor of regular expression.  This is not among those explicitly supported by Regex101, so it is not out of the question that a regex that worked there would not work with Puppet.  However, the Ruby-flavor online regular expression tester at [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) shows that your particular regular expression works just fine in Ruby, including the the matching group.

You don't show how you tried to obtain the matched group in your Puppet code, but the appropriate procedure is given in [Puppet's regular expression docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/lang_data_regexp.html). In particular:

> Within conditional statements and node definitions, substrings withing [sic]
> parentheses `()` in a regular expression are available as numbered
> variables inside the associated code section. The first is `$1`, the
> second is `$2`, and so on. The entire match is available as `$0`. These
> are not normal variables, and have some special behaviors: [...]

This is also reflected in [the documentation for conditional statements](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/lang_conditional.html).

You have only one capture group, so *inside the body of your conditional statement*, you can refer to the captured content as `$1`.  For example,

```
each($files) | $files_itm | {
  if $files_itm[1] =~ /"([^"]*)"/ {
    notify { "file ${1} seen": }
  }
}
```

Note well, however, that the capture group variables are only accessible within the body of the conditional statement, and outside any nested conditionals that have a regular expression match in their condition.  Also, it does not seem to be documented what the implications are if there are two or more regex-match expressions in the same conditional statement's condition.

### Update

But the update to the question and the error messages you presented in comments show that the problem you're struggling with is something altogether different.  The value associated with Hiera key `role::project::conf::files` is a *hash*, with string keys and array values, whereas you seem to expect an array according to the parameter default encoded into the class.  When you iterate over a hash and capture the entries in a single variable, that variable will take two-element array values, where the first (element 0) is the entry's key and the second (element 1) is corresponding value.

Thus, when the Hiera data presented in the question is bound to your `$files` parameter, your expression `$files_itm[1]` evaluates to array values such as `['file "/var/project/some_file.txt" 5333;', 'echo no;']`.  Those are not suitable left-hand operands for the `=~` operator, which is what the error message is telling you.

It's difficult to tell what you really want here, but this ought to at least avoid error (in conjunction with your YAML data):

```
each($files) | $itm_key, $itm_value | {
  if $itm_value[0] =~ /"([^"]*)"/ {
    notify { "file ${1} seen": }
  }
}
```

Comment: The if statement returns: Info: Retrieving pluginfacts Info: Retrieving plugin Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: Left match operand must result in a String value. Got an Array. at ../files.pp:33:7 on node mytest.server Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Comment: Strange, according to https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/lang_conditional.html#regex-capture-variables the if statement seems ok.

Comment: @JamesNorman, that error message reflects an altogether different problem than you asked about.  It is telling you that the expression `$files_itm[1]` evaluates to an array rather than to a string. You didn't show how variable `$files` gets its value, but if, for example, it is a class parameter of class `role::project::conf`, and it obtains its value by automatic data binding based on the given YAML, then that is to be expected (though it then exhibits a mild abuse of syntax).

Comment: Hey @John Bollinger, i have included also the class (in my question at the top)

Comment: @JamesNorman, I have updated this answer.  In the future, however, please try to avoid updating your SO questions in a way that completely changes what you are asking, especially after having received an answer.  If you realize that you have asked the wrong question, then the thing to do is respond appropriately to any answers you got in light of what you actually did ask, consider deleting the question if you didn't get any answers, and ask what you really wanted to know as a separate question.